# Using Singleton Service's Method as Recurring Hangfire Job

Tags: c#, hangfire

In my ASP.NET Core application, I have a Singleton service implemented:

```
services.AddSingleton<ITestCache, TestCache>();
```

This is my implementation of ITestCache:

```
public class TestCache : ITestCache
{
    private readonly ITestRepository _summaryRepository;
    private IEnumerable<_testSummary> _tests;

    public TestCache(ITestRepository summaryRepository)
    {
        _summaryRepository = summaryRepository;

        _tests = new List<_testSummary>();
    }

    public T GetCache<T>()
    {
        return (T)_tests;
    }

    public async Task UpdateCache()
    {
        _tests = await _summaryRepository.GetTests();
    }
}
```

I wish to use this Singleton interface and add it's UpdateCache() method as a recurring Hangfire job:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ITestCache>(x => x.UpdateCache(), Cron.Minutely());
```

The UpdateCache() method never fires.

I'm sure I'm missing something, or is this simply not a possibility?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to use singleton in such a scenario. What if they run in different BackgroundJobServers? Well, tehnically you can specify which server to run but still not the best practice.

For your question; I think the problem is not about the singleton. Does it run when it's not singleton? Does it fail only when you specify singleton?

Comment: I have used Singleton as the implementation method GetCache<T>() will be re-used in the application, and all instances of it's use need access to the same _cache field.

If I change it to transient, it still does not fire UpdateCache()

Comment: So, your issue is not about running singleton instances. 
Have you started your backgroundserver? Or what happens when you enqueue it instead of RecurringJob? Does it run it?

Comment: So strangely, it actually all works if I add the Hangfire dashboard and visit it, then the job starts to run minutely as expected, and update the Singleton service's _cache field each time the UpdateCache() method runs, which is exactly what I want. But if I don't visit the Hangfire dashboard, the job never runs